# Vertical space in tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, bar-chart

I would like to know how to space properly the bar produced by this code for them not to overlay the text  :

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\programming[1]{ 
    \renewcommand{\programming}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 0.55, xshift = 1cm]
        \foreach [count=\i] \x/\y in {#1} {
            \node[above right,minimum height = 0.25cm] at (0,\i+0.35) {\x};
            \draw[fill=lightgray,lightgray] (0,\i) rectangle (6,\i+0.4);
            \draw[fill=white,materialblue](0,\i) rectangle (\y,\i+0.4);
        }
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
}
    \programming{{C $\textbullet$ C++ $\textbullet$ R / 3}, {Java $\textbullet$ SQL $\textbullet$ \large \LaTeX / 3.5}, {HTML5 $\textbullet$ JS $\textbullet$ Python / 5}}  
\end{document}
```

producing :

[image: Example]

Comment: make from your code snippets one small, but complete and compilable document!

Comment: After 6 questions you probably know how to provide a MWE (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/). Considering you rate your LaTeX skills 3.5 out of 5 :).

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Well said ! Modifying it right away ;)

Comment: Did you test your MWE? I can't produce an output (pdflatex).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scale` doesn't change font size. consequently when you with `scale=...` you reduce rectangle size and distance between them rectangles overlap text which keep used font size. to overcome this problem, you have more possibilities, for example:

- not use `scale` and draw images in size which you like to have
- use `xscale` which scale only width of images

in the firs case you can obtain something like this:

[image]

and in the second for example at `xscale=0.55` like this:

[image]

slightly simplified *mwe* is:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\colorlet{materialblue}{blue!40}
\colorlet{lightgray}{black!15}
\newcommand\programming[1]{
        \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=0.55]
        \foreach \i/\j [count=\k from 0] in {#1} {
            \node[above right,
                  inner sep=2pt] at (0,\k) {\i};
            \fill[lightgray]        (0,\k) rectangle ( 6,\k-0.4);
            \fill[materialblue]     (0,\k) rectangle (\j,\k-0.4);
        }
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }

\begin{document}
\programming{{C $\textbullet$ C++ $\textbullet$ R / 3},
             {Java $\textbullet$ SQL $\textbullet$ \large \LaTeX / 3.5},
             {HTML5 $\textbullet$ JS $\textbullet$ Python / 5}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Just remove `scale=0.55`, and your diagram looks fine.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\colorlet{materialblue}{blue!40}
\colorlet{lightgray}{black!15}
\newcommand\programming[1]{ 
        \begin{tikzpicture}%[scale = 0.55]
        \foreach [count=\j] \x/\y in {#1} {
            \node[above right,minimum height = 0.25cm] at (0,\j+0.35) {\x};
            \draw[fill=lightgray,lightgray] (0,\j) rectangle (6,\j+0.4);
            \draw[fill=white,materialblue](0,\j) rectangle (\y,\j+0.4);
        }
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }

\begin{document}
\programming{{C $\textbullet$ C++ $\textbullet$ R / 3}, {Java $\textbullet$ SQL $\textbullet$ \large \LaTeX / 3.5}, {HTML5 $\textbullet$ JS $\textbullet$ Python / 5}}  

\end{document}
```

## Original answer, keeping `scale=0.55`

You need of course to have y-levels spaced by more than 1, which you can do for example by multiplying `\i` with a number  larger than 1.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\colorlet{materialblue}{blue!40}
\colorlet{lightgray}{black!15}
\newcommand\programming[1]{ 
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 0.55]
        \foreach [count=\i,evaluate=\i as \j using \i*1.5] \x/\y in {#1} {
            \node[above right,minimum height = 0.25cm] at (0,\j+0.35) {\x};
            \draw[fill=lightgray,lightgray] (0,\j) rectangle (6,\j+0.4);
            \draw[fill=white,materialblue](0,\j) rectangle (\y,\j+0.4);
        }
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }

\begin{document}
\programming{{C $\textbullet$ C++ $\textbullet$ R / 3}, {Java $\textbullet$ SQL $\textbullet$ \large \LaTeX / 3.5}, {HTML5 $\textbullet$ JS $\textbullet$ Python / 5}}  

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 What is the natural height of i?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Well, `\i` is just a counter, so 1, 2, 3, etc. The default unit vector is 1cm, but `scale=0.55` means it's 5.5mm here. (Which made me think of something, so thanks. Edit upcoming.)

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the explanation (I was wondering about the *1cm* part).